# True/False Question: $\neg P \to (Q\to R) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad Q\to (P\vee R)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I just took a discrete math midterm and this was the only True/False question I didn't know. Can someone please explain it to me?

> $$\neg P \to (Q\to R) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad Q\to (P\vee R)$$

Thanks!

Comment: In doubt you can always make a table of all 8 possible outcomes and compare. Have you tried that? A more elaborate method would be using the equivalence of $P\to Q$ and $\neg P\vee Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine when these two expressions are *false*.

- The first expression is false precisely when $P$ is false and $Q \to R$ is false, the latter occurring precisely when $Q$ is true and $R$ is false.
- The second expression is false precisely when $Q$ is true and $P \vee R$ is false, the latter occurring precisely when $P$ and $R$ are both false.

So both expressions have the property of being false if and only if $P$ is false, $Q$ is true and $R$ is false. Hence they're equivalent.

An alternative method is to prove this by truth table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $P \to Q \Leftrightarrow \lnot P \lor Q$

$$\neg P \to (Q\to R) $$
 $$\Leftrightarrow \neg P \to (\lnot Q\lor R)$$
 $$\Leftrightarrow P \lor (\lnot Q\lor R) $$
 $$\Leftrightarrow  \lnot Q \lor (P \lor R)$$
 $$\Leftrightarrow   Q \to (P \lor R)$$

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to do it is, if $P$ is false then the expression simplifies to

$$(Q \implies R) \iff (Q \implies R)$$

and if $P$ is true then you get

$$\top \implies (Q \implies R) \iff (Q \implies (\top \lor R))$$
$$\top \iff \top$$

---

You can also look at this from a more constructive logic point of view.

> $$\lnot P \implies Q \implies R$$

English: "If you cannot construct a P, then from a Q you can construct an R"

> $$Q \implies (P \lor R)$$

English: "From a Q, a P can be constructed or an R can be constructed".

If you think about it like "building an R", then it may be more obvious how the statements are equivalent.  Consider the following :

- $P$ is a disagreement
- $Q$ is any 2 people
- $R$ is a friendship

> $$\lnot P \implies Q \implies R$$

English: "If there are no disagreements then from 2 people we can make a friendship."

> $$Q \implies (P \lor R)$$

English : "If there are 2 people, then there is disagreement or there is a friendship."

For some people, putting logic in terms of things they have experience in rather than just being abstract makes it easier.